# CSS Absolute Positioning and Z-index on top

Tags: css, hover, absolute

With the following simplified code,

```js
$("[data-position]").each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: $(this).data('position')[0] + '%',
    top: $(this).data('position')[1] + '%',
  })
});
```

```css
ul         {position: relative;
            width: 15em;height: 15em;
            background: #0af;
            list-style: none}
strong,em  {padding: .5em}
strong     {background: #000; color: #fff;z-index:50}
em         {display: none;background: #fff;z-index:-1}
li:hover em{display: block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-position="[20,20]">
    <strong>A</strong>
    <em>This is an ay</em>
  </li>
  <li data-position="[10,10]">
    <strong>B</strong>
    <em>This is a bee</em>
  </li>
  <li data-position="[30,30]">
    <strong>C</strong>
    <em>This is a see</em>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The :hover-displayed element gets hidden by following siblings.

I tried to look at many similar questions and answers on this website but could not come up with an interesting answer. Changing the z-index or opacity levels do not work.

What could bring a hover-displayed element to the very top of z-index, whatever the position of siblings in the dom?

Answer (score 3):

[Go through the link to get the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/qvL1d9us/3/)

```
em {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add  `z-index:1;position:relative` in `em` class.

```js
$("[data-position]").each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: $(this).data('position')[0] + '%',
    top: $(this).data('position')[1] + '%',
  })
});
```

```css
ul         {position: relative;
            width: 15em;height: 15em;
            background: #0af;
            list-style: none}
strong,em  {padding: .5em}
strong     {background: #000; color: #fff;z-index:50}
em         {display: none;background: #fff;z-index:1;position:relative}
li:hover em{display: block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-position="[20,20]">
    <strong>A</strong>
    <em>This is an ay</em>
  </li>
  <li data-position="[10,10]">
    <strong>B</strong>
    <em>This is a bee</em>
  </li>
  <li data-position="[30,30]">
    <strong>C</strong>
    <em>This is a see</em>
  </li>
</ul>
```